# What does .I do when used within .SD, and how do you stipulate which one to use?

Tags: r, data.table

This stems from some code I created for this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094435/how-to-get-first-and-last-in-each-group-without-duplicate-rows) I asked. With sample data:

```
tmp_dt <- data.table(grp = c(1, 1, 1, 2), x = runif(4))
```

One can obtain the first and last rows in each group, without duplicates, by:

```
tmp_dt[, .SD[unique(c(1, .N))], by = grp]
#     grp         x
# 1:   1 0.0628539
# 2:   1 0.1552129
# 3:   2 0.5827001
```

I don't understand why using `.I` does not work to do the same thing:

```
tmp_dt[, .SD[.I %in% c(1, .N)], by = grp]
#     grp         x
# 1:   1 0.6244266
# 2:   1 0.2340571
```

It looks like `.I` refers to the row index within `.SD`, whereas `.N` refers to the number of rows in each group **outside** of `.SD`. How does one refer to `.I` so that it is *while grouping, it holds for each item in the group, it's row location in x*?

(I suppose one could do `tmp_dt[, .SD[seq_len(.N) %in% c(1, .N)], by = grp]` to achieve the desired result.)

Comment: Not sure which version of data.table you have.  I got error with `tmp_dt[, .SD[unique(c(1, .N)], by = grp]#
Error: unexpected ']' in "tmp_dt[, .SD[unique(c(1, .N)]"`

Comment: sorry, fixed the missing bracket

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the output with `.I` will be

```
tmp_dt[tmp_dt[, .I[unique(c(1, .N))], grp]$V1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but why doesn't it give the row index within each group, as per the helpfile?

Comment: @Alex If you are doing `.I %in% c(1, .N)`, `.I` refers to 1, 2, 3... to last row, while `1, ..N` gets reset every group

Comment: ah, I see. I misread that line in the helpfile. I can clearly see what is happening now: ` tmp_dt[, .(grp_ind = .I), by = .(grp)]` produces a new column `c(1,2,3,4)` and not `c(1,2,3,1)` as I expected.

Comment: Is `.I` always shorthand for `seq_len(nrow(x))`?

Comment: @Alex yeah, but it would be optimized

Comment: Thanks, so, after rereading the statement `While grouping, it holds for each item in the group, it's row location in x.` a few times, I still find it quite confusing, as `.I` does not have anything to do with grouping. The dot point is still valid and would be much clearer, imo, without this statement.

Comment: @Alex What it does is to extract the row positions much easier and subsetting with `.I` should be faster than `.SD[c(1, .N)]`

Comment: @Alex It's necessary to add the caveat "While grouping" since when not grouping `x[i, .I]` will *not* give rows in `x`, but rather rows within `x[i]`. Btw, `DT[, idx := rowid(g)]` will give a within-group index.